# BigQuery: Create table statement with struct

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

What is the syntax for creating table statement with struct fields? Below doesn't seem to work. I want to create a Record field such as `id.level1.level2.level3`.

```
CREATE TABLE mayumi_load_test.struct_cre(
STRUCT<STRUCT<STRUCT<STRUCT<id INT64> level1> level2>level3,
  t_ TIMESTAMP
)
PARTITION BY Date(t_)
```

Comment: show example of what exactly row you want to see in table's row

Comment: I included nested field I am trying to represent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> Create Table

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TABLE mayumi_load_test.struct_cre (
  id STRUCT<level1 STRUCT<level2 STRUCT<level3 INT64>>>,
  t_ TIMESTAMP
)
PARTITION BY DATE(t_)
```

> Insert Data

```
#standardSQL
INSERT INTO mayumi_load_test.struct_cre(id, t_) 
  VALUES(
    STRUCT(STRUCT(STRUCT(777))),
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  )
```